# Swift like structure in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, struct, structure

I have create one structure in swift, I want to create and use same with Objective c.

> Constant.Swift

```
struct Segues
{
    static let SignUpToSignIn = "SignUpToSignIn"
    static let SingInToForgotPassword = "SingInToForgotPassword"
    static let MatchesToProfile = "MatchesToProfile"
}
```

> ViewController.swift

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Segues.MatchesToProfile, sender: nil)
```

I have created above structure with swift now please help me to do same with Objective C. I have tried but I can not find the way that can be done with Objective-C struct.

**Is it possible using structure ? or there is any other way to achieve same.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a sidenote, in this case, you are better off using `enum`s for these, dont use `struct`s

Comment: number of ways..if you are dealing with constant  u can use enum, #define pragma, plist etc

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: See Martin R's link in his comment to the OP for a great solution.**

The simplest way I can think of is to make a class with only class methods to use (no instance variables or methods).

```
@interface Segues : NSObject

+ (NSString *)signUpToSignIn;
+ (NSString *)signInToForgotPassword;
+ (NSString *)matchesToProfile;

@end
```

Using them in code would look like this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:[Segues signUpToSignIn] sender: nil];
```

A simpler alternative is to use constants prefaced with `Segue`. This requires little code, but you lose the `Segues` namespace that a class gives you.

```
// In a .h file
extern NSString *const SeguesSignUpToSignIn;
extern NSString *const SeguesSignInToForgotPassword;
extern NSString *const SeguesMatchesToProfile;

// In a .m file
NSString *const SeguesSignUpToSignIn = @"SignUpToSignIn";
// copy for the others

// Usage
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:SeguesSignUpToSignIn];
```

There are a few other alternatives with enums and some methods to turn the enums into string values or using C structs, but those are a lot more work and more code for very little gain.

Comment: exactly for a little thing I have to do more code. And your answer still have more code to just get segue identifire.  Thanks for the help :)